# Why is this function from a polynomial to $\mathbb{Z}^{i+1}$ injective?

Tags: functions

Part of my professor's solution:

> Let $A$ = the set of all polynomials with integer coefficients. Let $A_i$ be the set of all
>   polynomials of degree $i$ with integer coefficients. Then $A = \bigcup A_i$, which is a countable union. Let
>   $h_i
> : A_i \rightarrow \mathbb Z^{i+1}$
>    be given by $$h_i(a_ix^
> i + a_{i−1}x^{
> i−1} + · · · + a_1x + a_0) = (a_i
> , a_{i−1}, . . . , a_1, a_0).$$ Clearly
>   $h_i$
>   is injective.

The last statement says that $h_i$ is injective, but I don’t see it. Can anyone explain it please?

Answer (score 1):

Notice that $h_i$ simply lists out the coefficients of the polynomial in question. The fact that $h_i$ is injective simply means that a polynomial of degree $i$ is uniquely determined by $i+1$-many numbers (its coefficients).

Comment: It is Z^(i+1). Someone edited my post and changed it.

Comment: Can we still prove it though, i.e. if f(x_1)=f(x_2) then x_1=x_2?

Comment: Sure. Say $f(p_1)=f(p_2)=(a_j)$, then $p_1 = \sum a_j x^j$, and $p_2 = \sum a_j x^j = p_1$.

Comment: Excellent response!